# Why is mixing 'from x import y' and 'import x' discouraged?

Tags: python, import

My script contains the following two lines as import-statements:

```
import os
from os import path
```

This seems a logical approach for my script: I use `os.path` very often, so I want to access it as `path`. On the other side, I need additional methods from `os`, but very rarely, so it is ok for me to write `os.access(...)` for example.

Why is this discouraged? `pychecker` for example complains about this.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you can't just write the 3 extra characters for `os.`?

Comment: why not just `path = os.path`

Comment: @lostyzd Why should you have to do that just to avoid an invalid warning?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's usually odd to both import a name from a module, and import the whole module.  In this case, you are importing a submodule, so it doesn't seem bad, though most people do just use "os.path" in their function calls.

Just because pychecker doesn't like it doesn't mean you can't do it.  Turn off that warning.

Comment: This is why it's a warning. Pychecker doesn't know if it's a problem, so you get informed.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably because your script is then importing `os.path` twice, using extra resources. Perhaps you should just call out all of the functions of `os` you will need.

Comment: Modules are only imported once, no extra resources are used.

Comment: `path` isn't being imported twice even in the "it has two names" sense, as it's a module, not a class in `os`.

Comment: In that case, it's probably just not recommended because it's confusing to maintain.

Comment: @Chriszuma it's because pychecker doesn't realize `path` is a module and not a class.